# Google search Infobox

Tags: google-search

I'm not sure if this answer should be posted here but I don't know where to ask for it, when I search my company name on google search I get the infobox on the right (this one for example):
[image]

But if I add to my research "Srl" which is a type of society I don't get the Infobox, what should I do in order to show it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try microdata markup to hint to them the full name.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146861?hl=en&ref_topic=4624916